# How can I fix the issue that IE plugin developed with firebreath is not valid?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7, firebreath

We developed an IE plugin with the firebreath framework. The plugin can run correctly in some environment with Windows 7 and IE10, but can't in another environment with the same OS and browser.

This error message is shown:

[image]

Comment: the picture can't be viewed. posted the log below:
[ xxx service] plugin is not valid (call initMessage)
connect_error error occurwhen sio socket try to connect. Error: xhr poll error reconnect_failed sio socket try too much reconnect attempts. 3 
invalid topic to unsubscribe!
reconnect_error error occur when sio socket try to reconnect. Error: xhr poll error
[xxx service] plugin is not valid (call releaseMessage)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to be certain, but my guess would be that your issue is your DLL has dependencies which aren't available on the system where it won't load; use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see what dependencies there are which aren't available.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! We checked by DW that all the dependencies are available. We found that the JS function of our customer's page call the interface incorrectly, while our test html page can call the interface of plugin correctly in same environment, so it is the bug in customer's page, maybe it is the compatible  issue.